# sed: replace first occurrence of a string in every line

Tags: sed, find-and-replace

Imagine I have a file like this:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES('1','<p><em>The lazy fox jumps again</em></p>bunch of other html<p><em>Is the lazy fox crazy?</em></p>')
INSERT INTO table VALUES('2','<p><em>The lazy fox jumps again</em></p>bunch of other html<p><em>Is the lazy fox crazy?</em></p>')
INSERT INTO table VALUES('3','<p><em>The lazy fox jumps again</em></p>bunch of other html<p><em>Is the lazy fox crazy?</em></p>')
```

And I wish to delete only the first occurrence of `<p><em>` and `</em></p>` so I end up with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES('1','The lazy fox jumps againbunch of other html<p><em>Is the lazy fox crazy?</em></p>')
INSERT INTO table VALUES('2','The lazy fox jumps againbunch of other html<p><em>Is the lazy fox crazy?</em></p>')
INSERT INTO table VALUES('3','The lazy fox jumps againbunch of other html<p><em>Is the lazy fox crazy?</em></p>')
```

... how can I do that with sed (or perl)? The statement...:

```
sed "1,/INSERT INTO/s/<p><em>//g"
```

... only replaces the first occurrence in the file, not on every line.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to process all lines with `INSERT INTO`, do not provide address range. If you want to only replace the first occurence of a string, do not provide `/g`:

```
sed -e '/INSERT INTO/s/<p><em>//' -e '/INSERT INTO/s/<\/em><\/p>//'
```

Comment: I edited your answer to include the second substitution the OP asked or. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it with `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's:<p><em>(.*?)</em></p>:$1:' infile
```

The `.*?` quantifier is non-greedy, so only the first pair of tags will be matched.

Output:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES('1','The lazy fox jumps againbunch of other html<p><em>Is the lazy fox crazy?</em></p>')
INSERT INTO table VALUES('2','The lazy fox jumps againbunch of other html<p><em>Is the lazy fox crazy?</em></p>')
INSERT INTO table VALUES('3','The lazy fox jumps againbunch of other html<p><em>Is the lazy fox crazy?</em></p>')
```